# Html Video show controls on page load

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

I want my video object to show the controls on page load, so the user is able to recognize that it's a video player. I am using the HTML5 video tag and it only works in Chrome so far, but I need it to work with IE.

```
<video poster="/pictures/Video01-Preview.png" preload="none" controls="controls">
    <source src="/download/Video01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: mention your IE version.

Comment: @Riad I am using IE 11, it doesn't seem to work with the preload setting set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give absolute path for video

Comment: this should be a problem for IE rather than a meta tag. did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not rigid to any solution, i suggest you to use [video js](http://www.videojs.com/) as best solution. Easy and works fine.

And also have a [TEST](http://html5test.com/) of your browser which supports or not

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if the preload setting of the video is disabled the controls won't show on page load even when the controls attribute is set. So the solution is to remove the preload setting and hope that either the browser of the user preloads the video and the user is going to watch it or the browser won't preload it.

```
<video poster="/pictures/Video01-Preview.png" preload="none" controls="controls">
   <source src="/download/Video01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```